# Why wont my nav bar toggle button work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Below is my code for navigation bar, I tried creating toggle button for my navigation bar when its at a small screen but it wont work .my drop down menu wont work too . Can someone please help me with the code. I am new to this , any help is appreciated. Any good suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Landing Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="Stylesheet/Css_Reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!--Navbar Header Start Here-->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MainNavBar">  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Image</a>
      </div>
      <!--Navbar Header End Here-->
      <!--Menu Start Here-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="MainNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
          <!--dropdown Menu Start-->
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">  
                           Product and Services
                            <span class="caret"></span>  
                        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Studio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Others</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <!--dropdown Menu End-->
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--Menu End Here-->
        <!--Right Aligned Menu Start-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--Right Aligned Menu End-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any error in the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337)? Because it seems to be working in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/WdXxjY?editors=1010) with some CDN ressources instead of yours. Look for red lines mentionning 404 in your console.

Comment: I'm going to take wild-guess that the directory you css-files are in isn't called `Stylesheet `?

Comment: Also, watch out for the spaces between each attribute... They are needed.

Comment: do i need jquery-2.1.4.min.js , bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.css for it to work ?

Comment: is it possible to wrote my own stylesheet similar to http://photoplay.sg/ nav bar

Comment: Is it possible that you state it if that's the case that you wrote your own ressources... ?

Comment: yes you need to import those libraries in order to dropdown to work. since it is based on scripts

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. I have added all the libraries needed. But recommended if you can download the mentioned scripts and put it a local folder, without referring from the link.

For the demo purpose I used the online scripting.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Landing Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!--Navbar Header Start Here-->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MainNavBar">  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Image</a>
      </div>
      <!--Navbar Header End Here-->
      <!--Menu Start Here-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="MainNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
          <!--dropdown Menu Start-->
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">  
                           Product and Services
                            <span class="caret"></span>  
                        </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Studio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Others</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <!--dropdown Menu End-->
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--Menu End Here-->
        <!--Right Aligned Menu Start-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--Right Aligned Menu End-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Download link**
Bootstrap (CSS and JS files)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/

If you want to include the files locally, refer the following link.
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-get-started.php

If you have further doubts, please do comment. Cheers!

**Edited Nav bar to right side**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Landing Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!--Navbar Header Start Here-->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MainNavBar">  
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Image</a>
      </div>
      <!--Navbar Header End Here-->
      <!--Menu Start Here-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="MainNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
          <!--dropdown Menu Start-->
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">  
                               Product and Services
                                <span class="caret"></span>  
                            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Studio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Others</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <!--dropdown Menu End-->
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--Menu End Here-->



      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: About your recommandation to download the ressources, instead of using the CDN's: I disagree. If a user visited another site using the same ressource (ex: bootstrap, which is quite popular), it will already be in the browser's cache. So the page load will be faster.

Comment: Agreed. There are different perspectives friend. But I can say, if you want to demo the website where there is not internet in a local machine, it will not load as it is. Having outside dependencies is not a good quality of work. And if a person first time loading the page, it will take time to load since it is referring outside, but if the files are setup locally, it will load faster and more reliable than using CDN. There can be various views, different opinions. It is up to the user to decide which is more good for his scenario

Comment: why isnt the login and register profile on the right ?

Comment: @OwenLim I edited the code, it seems there are two right nav bars, I change one to left, and login and register to right

Comment: I get your point of view... But demoing a website where there is no internet certainly is uncommon... Anyway.

Comment: i use the code from here , Navbar with Right-Aligned Menu . http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/bootstrap-for-beginners-navigation-bar-part-eleven2/

Comment: @OwenLim How do you want to display the nav bar? Everything on right side? 

LouysPatriceBessettew Well true hehe. Happened to me once two years back.

Comment: Please mark this question if it solves your answer. Because we also sacrifice our time to help you'll giving answers. Appreciate other people's effort @OwenLim

Comment: I Not sure what am i missing, i have the same code as the website but the login register isn't on the right

Comment: Check the second snippet in my answer, everything is aligned to right in the navigation (Except the image logo). Copy paste it, there should be a slight difference

Comment: At least put an upvote for the effort as an appreciation without being a selfish user at stackoverflow

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation, so it won't show. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Just after few hours, you untick the answer and play with other users reputation, this kind of behavior is not accepted at stackoverflow. Therefore, you will be reported for such behaviors.